# How do you say "a (romantic) date"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I could go with *rendevuo por amantoj*, but is there a more common way to say it?

Answer (score 11):

I have certainly heard the word "amrendevuo", a simple kunmetajxo of "amo" and "rendevuo".

No hits in Tekstaro, but 904 on google.

One of them is a [text](http://esperanto.net/literaturo/noveloj/) about the novel Amburĝono by Kuroda Masayuki:

> Ĝi temas pri la unua naiva amrendevuo de du malriĉaj gejunuloj.

Another is used in this [translation](http://www.ipernity.com/blog/mike59/716499) of La balo by Irène Nemirovsky, translated by Michel Dereyger:

> Ŝi fermis la okulojn, imagis junajn lipojn, avidan kaj teneran rigardon plenan de deziroj ... Haste, kvazaŭ ŝi kurus al amrendevuo, ŝi ĵetis sian negliĝon kaj ekvestiĝis.

Esperanto specialist Bertilo Wennergren points out that *rendevuo* is a common [false friend](http://bertilow.com/falska/) and uses *amrendevuo* to specify a romantic encounter.

Comment: At this time Tekstaro does have one single hit for "amrendevuo", from a detective novel by Claude Piron.

Answer (score 6):

*Rendevuo* is probably the most common, but yes, it is a general word. Courtship customs tend to vary from country to country and region to region, so I would not expect to find a single term with all the same nuances as the term that you perhaps have in mind. Best to describe if necessary.

I would not specify *por amantoj* - especially if the context suggested that it was two single people getting together.

For example (from an article from Monato):

> *La junulino kun kiu mi konatiĝis, ankaŭ ne estis terure bela kaj rimarkinda. Sed certe, ŝi ne estis komparebla kun mi. Do, ni konatiĝis dum dancoj. Mi invitis ŝin por sekva rendevuo. Ŝi konsentis.*

When the context is not sufficient to suggest that the meeting is for courtship purposes, it's possible to specify *amrendevuo*.

- *Ne temas pri **am**rendevuo.*

*Amrendevuo* is not as common as *rendevuo* even when talking about courtship, but it does have some traction in contexts where it's not already obvious that we're talking about a date.